# Roblox Lua run script when key pressed and you are a certain distance away

Tags: input, lua, roblox

I am trying to make a script in Roblox so that if you are 20 studs away and you press E it will bring up an NPC Dialog. It is being run inside a LocalScript. For the moment I just have it displaying a message when you press E, however it won't display the message.

```
local HumanoidRootPart = game.Players.LocalPlayer:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart")
local UserInputService = game:GetService("UserInputService")
local part = game.workspace.TableBox.TableTop

UserInputService.InputBegan:connect(function(keyCode)
    if keyCode.keyCode == Enum.KeyCode.E then
        if (part.Position - HumanoidRootPart.Position).magnitude < 20 then
            print("E has been pressed")
        end
    end
end)
```

I am also getting this error in the output(in orange):

> Infinite yield possible on 'Players.icrann:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart")'

I expect `local HumanoidRootPart = game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart")` to work, but it ends up bring up the error:

> Players.icrann.PlayerScripts.Script:1: attempt to index field 'Character' (a nil value)

And also when I play the game my character in the explorer looks like this:

[image: Explorer]

Comment: I think it should be: `if (part.Position - HumanoidRootPart.Position).magnitude >= 20`

Comment: My code will definitely work better with your suggestion, however unfortunately it doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
local HumanoidRootPart = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart") --It is .LocalPlayer, cuz localplayer is the player on that client
local UserInputService = game:GetService("UserInputService")
local part = workspace.TableBox.TableTop

UserInputService.InputBegan:connect(function(keyCode)
    print(HumanoidRootPart.Position)
    if keyCode.keyCode == Enum.KeyCode.E and (part.Position - HumanoidRootPart.Position).magnitude <= 20 then
        print("E has been pressed")
    end
end)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this for the HumanoidRootPart.

```lua
local Player = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer
local character = Player.Character or Player.CharacterAdded:Wait()
local HumanoidRootPart = character:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart")
```

Comment: Unfortunately when I try do this it brings up an error:  Players.icrann.PlayerScripts.Script:1: attempt to index field 'Character' (a nil value)

Comment: @CrannMoroney I have edited the code try this again.

Answer (score 0):

After many hours of research I found out a way to do this it isn't 100% working but it is almost there.

```
local HumanoidRootPart = workspace.icrann:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart")
local UserInputService = game:GetService("UserInputService")
local part = workspace.TableBox.TableTop

UserInputService.InputBegan:connect(function(keyCode)
    print(HumanoidRootPart.Position)
    if keyCode.keyCode == Enum.KeyCode.E and (part.Position - HumanoidRootPart.Position).magnitude <= 20 then
        print("E has been pressed")
    end
end)
```

The only problem now is getting the players username. If you have any extra suggestions on how to do this please add a comment or an answer. Thank you to everyone who tried to help.